# How to identify entries where a data does not exist in a table with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to pull all data where the Article exist in Table 1 but not in Table 2 **when** the CnTy is PB00. So if the article exist in Table 2 for other CnTy that is NOT PB00, I still want it on the report. I've been using a where CnTY != 'PB00' and it just filters out PB00 instead of giving me Articles that do NOT contain 'PB00'. I don't think I can use a left join because of the added condition.

This is what I have:

```
select* from T1
join T2 on T1.Article = T2.Article
WHERE T2.CNTY != 'PB00'
```

[Sample data for Table 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRMd4.png)

In this particular example, this entire article shouldn't be included because of PB00 records. However if the article only contained ZOID type then it needs to be identified

Comment: Please don't use images for data... use formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from T1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where T2.Article = T1.Article and
                        T2.CNTY = 'PB00'
                 );
```

Comment: @IngoB . . . Huh?  `not exists` is optimal in most databases.  I have no idea what is confusing about `select 1`, so that requires some explanation.  As for efficiency, the `select` columns are ignored so there is no difference in performance, except that `1` might save a few machine cycles during the compilation phase.

Comment: Hi, the issue I'm having is still with the 'PB00'. I get the same # of results when I include T2.CNTY = 'PB00' and when I exclude it. It seems the result is giving me all article that is in T1 but not in T2 (but not considering the CNTY)

Comment: @Yundengogo . . . That would suggest that no `CNTY` has that value.  You may need to be careful with "look-alike" values -- values that look the same but are not the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was reading the data wrong, you're right. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` as follows:

```
select distinct t1.* 
  from T1
Left join T2 on T1.Article = T2.Article and T2.CNTY = 'PB00'
 Where T2.Article is null;
```